# Canvas not being drawn html5 (javascript, closures)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, closures

If I remove the "alert(stepHor);" line, nothing is going to be drawn on my canvas. But if I let the alert(stepHor), everything goes perfectly as expected. If it had an img.onload of something like that, I would understand, but here I don't. Does it have something to do with "closures"? Thanks in advance.

```
function draw(imageData) {  
    var canvas=document.getElementById('bg'); 
    if(canvas.getContext){ 
        var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.scale(0.4,0.4);

        var stepHor=Math.floor(imageData.width/imax);
        var stepVer=Math.floor(imageData.height/jmax);
        alert(stepHor);

        for(i=0;i<=imax;i++){
            for(j=0;j<=jmax;j++){   
                var index=(j*stepVer+Math.floor((imageData.height-jmax*stepVer)/2))*(4*imageData.width)+(i*stepHor*4)+Math.floor((imageData.width-imax*stepHor)/2)*4;//the first 'Math.floor' member is to center the image vertically, the second 'Math.floor' member is to center the image horizontally
                var red=imageData.data[index];
                var green=imageData.data[index+1];
                var blue=imageData.data[index+2];
                var alpha=imageData.data[index+3];
                ctx.fillStyle='rgb(' +red+ ',' +green+ ',' +blue+ ')';
                ctx.fillRect(wireWidth*i,wireHeight*j,wireWidth,wireHeight);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When/how is this being function called ? and where does the `imax` variable come from ?

Comment: imax and jmax are global variables, and I define them this way: `var imax=Math.floor($(window).width()/wireWidth);
var jmax=Math.floor($(window).height()/wireHeight);`  where a 'wire' is actually a 'pixel' which size I define in global variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before drawing on canvas you need to wait before initialization of the page.

Call function in `body.onload` or somewhat.

Blocking alert gives browser enough time to init unless you're a robot with 10ms reaction speed :-D

Comment: That would be my first thought as well, the alert is creating a delay whcich ensures the dom is loaded. Instead the function should only be called after the dom is loaded.

Comment: Since when does `canvas` need the DOM to be ready? http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/9xxM8/

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot to mention that in my html page, the function imageReader(this) is called when my image has finished loading, and at the end of this function, I call the actual function draw(imageData)

Comment: That was it, I wrapped the for loops in a $(document).ready and that worked. Thanks!

Comment: @Niklas Yes, you're right. It is required for only excanvas on old IE and for images. I suggested wrong thing, but nevertheless guessed the answer :-D